# Xcode nav bar background remove image

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I wanted to change the background of the NAV Bar and I used

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my image.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

When I go the next view I wanted to remove the image. I used

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

}

But there is a problem when I go back to the first screen. The NAV Bar is without the image. I want to set the image on a particular view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the background image in `- (void)viewWillAppear` instead of `- (void)viewDidLoad`.
The reason is simple. `- (void)viewDidLoad` is called one and only one time for any view (after the alloc-init phase of the view). When you load the first screen again, `- (void)viewWillAppear` will be called instead of `- (void)viewDidLoad` for the first screen. I suppose this is the problem.

Comment: No, the same problem, I tried this. In fact, when I put it in `viewWillAppear` the image doesn't show

Comment: Try `self.navigationController.navigationBar`instead of `UINavigationBar`in viewWillAppear.

Comment: `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    
}`

This is my solution. Thanks a lot!